# How to display metadata records in dropdown menu in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">           
            <lightning-combobox
                name="progress"
                label="Step 2: Choose Center"
                value=""
                placeholder="choose one..."
                options={options}
                onchange={handleChange}
                required>
            </lightning-combobox>
        </div>
    </div>   
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
//import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import fetchMetaListLwc from '@salesforce/apex/Dropdownmenucontroller.fetchMetaListLwc';
//import Dropdown_menu_items__c from '@salesforce/schema/Dropdown_menu__mdt.Dropdown_menu_items__c';
export default class Demo extends (LightningElement) {
   // value = '';
    @wire(fetchMetaListLwc)
    options;
    get responsereceived(){
        if(this.options){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

@AuraEnabled( cacheable=true )  
    public static List < Dropdown_menu__mdt > fetchMetaListLwc() {     
        List < Dropdown_menu__mdt > fetchMeta = [ SELECT Id, MasterLabel, Dropdown_menu_items__c, Menu_Items_Url__c FROM Dropdown_menu__mdt ];
        system.debug(fetchMeta);
        return fetchMeta;
    }
```

I'm facing problem in js controller, to know how to put the fetch metadata records in dropdown menu

Comment: You need to transform your data in the desired format that is supported by [lightning-combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation), generally this is done by using a wrapper/inner class in apex to form the data.